# How to update UIImageView async?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView with lots of UIButton. Large local images displayed in buttons. I use this code to load large image async(UIButton's category):

```
- (void)asyncLoadImageAtPath:(NSString *)fullPath forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setImage:image forState:state];
        });
    });
}
```

initWithContentsOfFile: running in other thread, while update UI by setImage:forState: in main thread. But setImage:forState: costs too much time, it makes UITableView scroll not smoothly.

So is there any way to update UIImageView or UIButton's UI async?

Special thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For async images I use [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView), it works fine on tableViews

Answer (score 1):

check out the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), This library provides a category for UIImageVIew with support for remote images coming from the web.